# NodeJS app build is successful (Render) but Application Error in render at the launch. Status is failed, no error logs

Tags: node.js, deployment, render

Status shown failed but in console log deployed successfully & server is up.

[Image for your referance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KByrJ.png)

[app url](https://node-api-d447.onrender.com/)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am running into the same issue with a simple express node app on Render. I can't explain it. One thing I did try was creating a `PORT` env var to match what the server was listening on but that didn't seem to make a difference. Have you had any luck with this since you asked the question on here?

Answer (score 10):

On Render, if your app is configured for a health check and it does not receive a response code between 200 - 399, it will fail... so the deployment will fail as well.

https://render.com/docs/deploys#health-checks

In my Node/Express app on Render, I was able to get a successful deployment by doing this in my server.js file:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendStatus(200)
})
```

For context, I'm using Render to host a Google reCAPTCHA validator. I don't need to load anything on the homepage, so just sending the status code was enough (https://github.com/markhillard/invisible-recaptcha-validator).

By sending the status code directly to where the health check was running (in my case it's the root directory: `/`), it was able to receive a 200 "OK" status and then the deployment finally went "Live".

I'm not sure if this will help your particular situation, but maybe it's worth a shot to try this.

Answer (score 0):

For all those people who actually need to display a file:

```
  res.status(200).sendFile(...)
```

should work out fine